# Why is there a resistor in the feedback section of this buffer circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, buffer

[image]

When I searched for op amp buffer circuits on internet, I found this picture.

I just want to use it as a buffer circuit. So, obviously the gain of this configuration will be 1. I would like to put 0 Ω resistor as Rf in that location.

Is it ok or do I need to connect those two lines without resistor  in the middle. If I put a 0 Ω resistor in that place what will happen? Will there be any instability problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Why is there a resistor in the feedback section of this buffer
> circuit?*

If the op-amp has significant input bias currents (rather than offset currents) then making \$R_F = R_1||R_2\$ has some DC accuracy benefit.

If the op-amp has an unstable unity gain bandwidth, then using \$R_F\$ might just make the difference between the circuit oscillating or not because gain will naturally rise at higher frequencies due to the parasitic input capacitance at the inverting input.

Adding \$R_F\$ to op-amps that don't suffer from either of the above will degrade noise performance because the inverting input's parasitic capacitance will make the AC gain at higher frequencies significantly higher than unity. This may or may not be regarded as a problem.

Personally, since 1980 when I first started designing with op-amps, I bet I haven't used a feedback resistor in any unity-gain op-amp circuit since the mid 1990s (because of the availability of quality op-amps with really low bias currents).

Comment: Since I don't use AC signal, I think it is not needed to think of AC gain here. Am I right?

Comment: I am using LM 2902 and it has 20 nA as input bias current. Should I use the feedback resistor now?

Comment: @CNA no, that would be naïve. Any signal has an AC content and a DC content and, noise is an AC phenomena too.

Comment: The input bias current of the LM2902 is typically 45 nA according to the data sheet. I cannot tell YOU whether you should use one because I have no idea what your DC offset error budget is.

Comment: I can bear upto 10mV of DC offset as an offset error

Comment: Given the values for your input resistors, how much DC offset will be created by the typical bias current of 45 nA? You may also want to consider the worst case input bias current stated in the data sheet. You might also want to review a lot of your previous questions that have good answers - have you given up accepting answers since 2018? Do you feel that isn't your responsibility any more? Do you think that this is how this site works? Or maybe you just forgot?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am just curious to know the things as am a newbie. Accepting answers are not problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

An OpAmp is never ideal. When the feed impedance seen by the two inputs (+ and -) is equal, certain non-ideal aspects cancel out. Hence the value of Rf should be the parallel of R1 and R2.

Comment: The "non-ideal" aspects are the input currents (normally neglected), which are assumed to be equal. However, they are not! Nevertheless, the resistor Rf cannot "cancel out" these effects but it can reduce the error,

Comment: Ok. What if I put 0 Ω resistance in the place of Rf? Can I use it for buffer circuit?

Comment: @ Wouter, Could you be more elaborate?

Comment: CNA, of course, you can. As the result, the quiescent DC output voltage (offset) will be some millivolts maximum. If this is not a problem for your application....

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of opamp you use, whether the error due to the input bias current and different impedances seen by the "+" and the "-" inputs matter or not. If you use a modern opamp, you most likely can set the feedback resistor to zero ohms.

See also the summary of this application note, where one can read:
"With respect to adding a balancing resistor, if the op amp is CMOS, JFET, or bipolar with input bias current cancellation, you probably don’t need one."

[Analog devices application note](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/studentzone/studentzone-june-2017.html#)

Comment: Hi, I planned to use LM2902